# Does Mutual information utilize spatial information to calculate image similarity?

Tags: image-processing, information-theory, terminology, image-registration

To calculate images similarity based on Mutual Information (MI), histogram and join histogram is required. In the literature, there are 2 contradict opinions about MI operation. 1. MI does not utilize image spatial information to calculate the similarity. 2. MI is embedded spatial information indirectly by joint histogram. I thought that may I misunderstand the MI methodology.

First opinion

> ... mutual information (MI) considers only statistical information, while
>   spatial information is completely neglected. (Abdel-Basset et al. 2017)

Second opinion:

> Several works (Gao et al., ..) have adopted the joint histogram
>   of the image pair to embed spatial information into an intensity
>   distribution. (Xu et al. 2016)

I believe the second opinion is the right one. But I find many papers agree with the first one.  Which of the two groups do you believe in? why is another group wrong?